# Specify type of rxjs observable's "error" handler

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Suppose I have some operation that returns an observable.

```
this.loginService
  .post<IResponse>(url, { username, password })
  .subscribe(
    next => { /* I know the type of next */ },
    error => { /* Can I specify type of err, or is it always any? */ }
  );
```

The type of `next` is something I can set - in this case `IResponse`.

What about `error` - can I specify it's type somehow? Or is it always `any`, and I'll always need to typecast within the handler?

Comment: You can never assume the type of an error caught by an observable. You can use instantof operator to check the type at run time. What I do is catch all errors in a service and then only forward errors of a given type. Consumers of that service can then assume the error type downstream.

Comment: @Reactgular That was what I initially assumed until I saw the answer below - do you maybe have an example of that? I also prefer not to assume a type, it feels like I'm breaking the type system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been my experience that a service that yields observables from a HTTP operation should never emit uncaught HTTP errors. It creates a lot of boilerplate code in the consumers of that service, and forces consumers to handle HTTP specific issues.

I also think that services should *not* catch *all* types of errors, but only the known and expected errors. Requiring the application itself to handle edge cases using an error interceptor.

```
export interface ILoginResponse {
   //...
}

export interface IServiceResponse<TType> {
   success: boolean;
   payload?: TType;
}

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {

   public login(options: any): Observable<IServiceResponse<ILoginResponse>> {
      return this.httpClient.post<ILoginResponse>('login', options).pipe(
          map(payload => ({success: true, payload})),
          catchError(err => {
              if(err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                  // handle http errors here, maybe retry, update headers, etc..
                  return of({success: false});
              }
              // this error is unexpected, we don't know what to do
              // let the app interceptor handle it, but upstream observables
              // won't know what to do either. Our app has crashed...
              // You can return success false, but why handle this error?
              return throwError(err);
          });
   }
}
```

Why should you do the above?

Any time you use a *route* resolver that emits an uncaught error it will *fail* route transition. The router will basically crash. The user will basically just see a blank page, because resolvers have no error handling fall back.

The above only catches HTTP errors, because that's the only kind that we think should be thrown. Another kind of error should be seen as a bug.

If a component calls this service, then the programmer should check the `success` flag for `true` before *trusting* the emitted value. This can be filtered if the business logic does not care if it fails, or the component can visually show the user that it failed to perform the HTTP request. Either way, the HTTP error response does not go to the app error interceptor.

This is just an *approach*. People do their HTTP stuff all differently. The other answer correctly answers your question.

Comment: @lonix You should consider these suggestions

Comment: I think this is bad advice.What you are doing is just turning the error state into a boolean success state. Consumers *still* need to handle that boolean flag, and you have created more boilerplate interfaces that include the flag.
The second reason is also wrong. Resolvers are there to provide data that is *needed* to display the view. If the data is not there, such as in the case of a success = false, the view cannot be displayed. You can (and should) still manage the observable error in the resolver with a catchError and redirect to an appropriate view.

Answer (score 3):

You can use parentheses for what you want to achieve:

```
this.loginService
  .post<IResponse>(url, { username, password })
  .subscribe(
    (next: TypeOfYourResponse) => {...},
    (error: TypeOfYourErrorResponse) => {...}
  );
```

---

For further reading on arrow functions:

https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/arrow-function

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/arrow-functions.html

---

### Update 2024

As RxJS deprecated all signatures of `subscribe()` that take more than 1 argument since `v6.4`, it needs to be as following:

```
this.loginService
  .post<IResponse>(url, { username, password })
  .subscribe({
    next: (response: TypeOfYourResponse) => {...},
    error: (err: TypeOfYourErrorResponse) => {...}
  });
```

Comment: Ahh nice didn't think of that. BTW, if it's the wrong type, will it throw an error or just carry on?

Comment: afaik, it not for runtime as JavaScript does not have types on runtime. But it is for compile-time. I'm not 100% sure btw

Comment: If its the wrong type, it will silently carry on and probably fail at runtime. This is the general rule when an unchecked `any` is involved.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it using catchError operator:

```
this.loginService
  .post<IResponse>(url, { username, password })
  .catchError<TypeOfYourErrorResponse>(() => // Your catch callback)
  .subscribe(
    next => { /* I know the type of next */ },
  );
```

Comment: I can't remember, but I think you have to define two generic parameters for `catchError`. Maybe the error type and the returned type. I'm not sure the signature accepts a single parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I really liked @Reactgular's accepted answer

I like the fact it will make the consumer think about errors when they have to check success status!  However sometimes the consumer may want to get and display an error from the server, so I've changed it a little:

```
// DON'T FORGET THESE!
import { Observable, of } from "rxjs";
import { catchError, map } from "rxjs/operators";

export interface ILoginResponse {
   //...
}

export interface IServiceResponse<TType> {
   payload?: TType;
   error?: HttpErrorResponse;
}

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {

   public login(options: any): Observable<IServiceResponse<ILoginResponse>> {
      return this.httpClient.post<ILoginResponse>('login', options).pipe(
          map(payload => ({ payload })),
          catchError(err => of({ error: err }))
   }
}
```

No need for success flag, just check if you have a payload or error

```
loginService.login().subscribe(response => {
   if (response.payload) {
      // success...
   }
   else if (response.error) {
      // handle the error
   }
},
```

I think return all errors, the client might not care so it can be ignored, but it will be there if they do care; if you want to handle specific errors, use an `HttpInterceptor` somewhere else...